# Count the number of differences between two string in php?

Tags: php, string, compare

I want to compare two string due to length of shorter string and return the number of differences theme. for example:

```
$first_str = "abcdez";
$second_str= "abhdx";
```

Now due to length of `$second_str` that is shorter, So must be return 2. Because they differ only in the third and fifth index. In fact are compared equal index.
Is there a function for it in php? if not, can you help me for writing code?

Comment: You want to compare the chars?

Comment: Why `2`? `c`, `e`, and `z` are not present in the second string.

Comment: @Patrick Mlr . yes. first char from first string with first char from second string ...

Comment: @Digipng  this is what you want:- https://eval.in/643475

Comment: Could be the inverse of that @Anant, https://eval.in/643477. I'd expect the difference to be 5 though, because there are 5 differences between the 2 strings. Guess the OP isn't responding to my comments though..

Comment: @chris85. because length of second string is shorter so they are compared to 'x' char.

Comment: why 2, i think 3?

Comment: @Digipng   do you want this:- https://eval.in/643482   or this:- https://eval.in/643475

Comment: Short alteration of @Anant first comment, https://eval.in/643485. Per specs though this doesn't actually check content if the length is the same, or if `$str2` is greater than `$str1`.

Comment: @Digipng  as you said `"So must be return 2 Because they differ only in the third and fourth index."` is not correct because it's 3 and 5  `h and x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps. I forked the comment from Anant.

```
$first_str = "abcdez";
$second_str= "abhdx";

$first_str_array = str_split($first_str);

$second_str_array = str_split($second_str);

$first_count = count($first_str_array);
$second_count = count($second_str_array);

if (($first_count - $second_count) > 0) {
    $count = $first_count - $second_count;
    unset($first_str_array[$first_count-$count]);
} else if (($second_count - $first_count) > 0){
    $count = $second_count - $first_count;
    unset($second_str_array[$second_count-$count]);
}

$final_difference = array_diff($first_str_array,$second_str_array);
```

Comment: I added count($final_difference) to end and worked well. Thankyou for The most complete answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are nice for such things. I didn't test it but it should work

```
$a_first_str = str_split($first_str);
$a_second_str = str_split($second_str);

$diff=array_diff_assoc($a_second_str, $a_first_str);
```

You will have an array showing the diff

Comment: Yeah, thats will do it. Just `count()` the `$diff` now and you got the number of differences.